# android-arabic charecter in json string is showing like?

Tags: android, json

For some reasons I need to use a json string inside my application .this is the string variable content .I logged this variable and this is the content :

```
{"contacts": [{ "name" : "سلام"},{  "name" : "علیک"}] }
```

When I use my json class to show this varibale,I get   ?????? instead of arabic characters .

my json class is working fine when I get arabic charecter from web service but it doesn't work fine when I get these characters from a variable inside my application .

Comment: please provide more context: what json library do you use, how do you get the arabic value into a variable, what do you do with it, android version ... because I'm using 'org.json.JSONObject' on 4.3 and I don't have any problems with arabic characters (tried UI, logcat, breakpoints and I can properly see them)